# Regular Expressions to sanitize phone numbers

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to write a script that uses sed and takes takes a text file containing phone numbers with area code 301 followed by 209(  3012093934, (301) 2093935, (301)209-3936  ). I have to remove the blank, dash, parenthesis where they separate the area code and the number. Then I have to write the correct numbers to another file; the correct numbers meaning the ones that start by area code 301, followed by 209 and exactly 4 more digits.

So my regular expression is this but doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
sed -n 's/(^301[\- ]*)/(209)/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$\)/p'
```

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*\(301\).*\(209\).*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1\2\3/w foobar'
```

This removes all the characters before `301` (to account for `(309)`), and zero or more occurrences of space and `)` after `301` with exactly four digits after `209` ignoring any non-digit characters.  The output is written to `foobar`.

Answer (score 4):

remove all characters that are not a digit, and then remove lines that do not start as desired, finally remove those that are not 10 characters:

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' -e '/^301209/!d' -e '/^.\{10\}$/!d'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would start off by removing the undesirable characters with `tr` and then filter with `grep`:

```
tr -d '() -'|grep '301209[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'
```

Comment: @don_crissti There are no square brackets either: just `tr -d '() -'`

Comment: I came up with this change after failing with `tr -d '() -'`.  You are right though, the problem is not related to the unneeded brackets.

Comment: jp - hot or cold?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ne '/^ *\(+1\)\{0,1\} *(\{0,1\} *301 *)\{0,1\} *209 *-\{0,1\}\( *[0-9]\)\{4\} *$/s/[^0-9]*//gp'
```